# An alert message popping up after opening Spyder3 that "You have missing dependencies! rope >=0.9.4: None (NOK)"

Tags: error-handling, dependencies, spyder

I have installed Spyder3 in Ubuntu but as soon i open it. A window is opening and saying:

> "You have missing dependencies! rope >=0.9.4: None (NOK)"

How to resolve this bug?

Please reply with the solution.[I got the window as soon as i open spyder3 in ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm7W1.png)

Comment: How did you install Spyder?

Comment: i installed it through 'Ubuntu Software'

Comment: You need to run in a terminal `sudo pip install rope_py3k` to solve this problem.